# Passing 2D bytearray to C Jni

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I wanted to pass on a 2D byte array from Java to C++ using JNI, everything seems fine, but I can't get the value of the third array.

Java:

```
    byte[][] b = new byte[3][];
    byte[] b1= new byte[]{0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4};
    byte[] b2= new byte[]{0x5,0x6,0x7,0x8};
    byte[] b3= new byte[]{0x9,0x9,0x9,0x9};
    b[0]=b1;
    b[1]=b2;
    b[2]=b3;
    sendData(b);
```

C++:

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_jni_JniExample_sendData___3_3B
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray data)
{
        jboolean isCopy;
        uint8_t** y = new uint8_t*[3];
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
                jbyteArray bytearray  = (jbyteArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(data, i);
                y[i]  = (uint8_t *)env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(bytearray, &isCopy);
                cout << i << " " << y[i]  << endl;
        }

}
```

The output that I get is:

```
0 0x1 0x2 0x3 0x4

1 0x5 0x6 0x7 0x8

2
```

I can't reach the values for the third array. Am I using GetPrimitiveArrayCritical correctly?

Comment: Note: `isCopy` is FYI only. You might as well pass `NULL` instead of `&isCopy` since you are not using it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking two or three rules given in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetPrimitiveArrayCritical_ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical):

1. GetXXX, if successful, must be followed by a ReleaseXXX.
2. GetXXXCritical can be nested, that is, you should release in reverse order.
3. And, it's probably best not to call I/O or other long-running functions while in a critical region.